# Change loop on object to run better

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Im getting the following array of objects and find a matching for specific object property
This is the array

Im trying to find if path is equal to reqPath,if yes exit with true.

```
 {
      "prov": [
        {
          "sa": {
            "path": "test2",
            "fn": "save"

          },
          "del": {
            "path": "test1",
            "fn": "delete"
          }
        }

  ]
}
```

The following code is **working OK** but my question there is a way with loadash or other tool to write it nicer/better?

```
validatePath: function (configs, reqPath) {
        var isValid = false;
        _.each(configs, function (config) {
            _.each(config, function (providers) {
                providers.forEach(function (keys) {
                    _.each(keys, function (properties) {
                        if (properties.path === reqPath) {
                            isValid = true;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        return isValid;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: `map` and `filter` would go a long way here.

Comment: @torazaburo- Done update my question ,let me know if its clearer now.

Comment: @JaredSmith- example will  be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
var passed = _.filter(configs, function(config) {
    return config.prov.some(function(obj) {
        return obj.path === reqPath;
    });
});
```

This will filter the configs for ones that have providers that have at least one property object that passes the filter.

Comment: Thanks but what is some? config.prov.some im getting error Cannot read property &#39;some&#39; of undefined

Comment: Array.some returns true if any element in the array passes the provided filter function. It also returns true as soon as any element passes, obviating the need to traverse the entire array except in the worst case.

Comment: I just realized your data structure is nested a level deeper than I solved for, however you can apply the same strategy to any arbitrary level of nesting (or make it a recursive function and be done with it)

Comment: Thanks,I need that when it find match to exit,is it possible to do that?

Comment: If its `node.js` and you really want it to exit, `process.exit(0);` will do just that. If we're talking in a browser or you just want the loop to exit rather than quit the entire process, then I recommend implementing `Array.some`-for-objects-used-as-hashtables yourself. Or you could always go back to a plain-jane `for` loop (with a `break`), but those have the drawback of being less testable and composable, which is (I'm assuming) why you went with a more functional approach in the first place.